# How to trigger the input value using trigger() in javascript in laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel

```
<div id ="id1">
<button id="ref">refresh</button>
<input  class= "graph" value= "44">
</div>
<div id ="id2">
<button id="ref">refresh</button>
<input  class= "graph" value= "14">
</div>
<div id ="id3">
<button id="ref">refresh</button>
<input  class= "graph" value= "54">
</div>
```

This is my **blade file**.

On clicking the **refresh**button, the value should be updated in the *input field* in each parent div(id1, id2, id3) respectively.

**Event file**:

```
 public $id, $value;
 
    public function __construct($id, $value)
    {
       $this->id = $id;
       $this->value = $value;
    }

  
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('my-channel');
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
class SampleController extends Controller
{


    public function getId($id, $value)
    {

      $res = event(new ValueChange($id, $value));
      return view('welcome');

    }
}
```

**Route file:**

```
Route::get('/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\SampleController@getId');
```

**Js file:**:

```
 var pusher = new Pusher('xxxxxxxxxx', {
        cluster: 'ap3',
        encrypted: true
      });
      var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
      channel.bind('App\\Events\\ValueChange', function(data){
      target = data.id;
      value = data.value;
    });
```

How to bind the value through **JS Trigger()**?

When I pass the event in the tinker,

```
event(new App\Events\ValueChange('id1', 9));
```

The static value `44` should be replaced by `9`, after clicking the `refresh`button when I pass in the URL like `http://www.project.test/id1`.

How to use trigger() to bind the value on clicking refresh?

Could someone please help?

Many thanks:-)

Comment: Just curious why you dont use a button. e.g. `<button name="refresh" value="44">Refresh</button>` and have multiple of them.

Comment: @MichaelMano, It can be `button` insteadof `a` for refresh. But I need the value from the input field.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem. Do you have any sort of event listener attached to the `a` tags to listen for clicks?

Comment: @apokryfos, I don't have any event listener attached to the a tags.

Comment: Then what purpose do those `a` tags serve? They are now buttons which changes things since a `button` would trigger a submit and full page refresh, though still not clear how that is handled